# Is there a more DRY approach for creating React text input form elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, architecture, dry

In React and React Native the accepted practice to include `<input>` form fields is to include an `onChange` handler that updates the `state` on every keystroke. e.g. :

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.valueField1} onChange={this.handleChangeField1} />
```

The state is updated in order to prevent the value from being restored to the original value while the user is typing.

This leads to a lot of repeated code, thus violating the old DRY (Do not repeat your self) principle. e.g. (based in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)):

```
  handleChangeField1(event) {
    this.setState({valueField1: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeField2(event) {
    this.setState({valueField2: event.target.value});
  }
```

The problem here is having to repeat the field name "Field1" 3 times instead of one (just for the declaration) and forcing the creation of an onChange logic that can easily (and by mistake), alter the standardized expected behavior of the UI components for the APP users.

**The question:** Is there a less verbose, less repeating and less risky way to include `<input>` fields in ReactJS/React-Native apps?

When I talk about preserving the component´s native behavior, I´m mainly thinking about not changing the value while the user is typing.

As a reference, in simple HTML/VanillaJS example we would just add the `<input value="{ServerSideValue}" name="field1">` once and then get the value from field1 wherever we need it, thus preserving the native component behavior and without repeating the field1 more than once in the declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pattern that we use a lot. I'm pretty sure it answers your question:

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          name="firstName"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="Enter your first name"
          value={this.state.firstName}
        />
        <input
          name="lastName"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="Enter your last name"
          value={this.state.lastName}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I made an example for you:

[image: Edit Form State example]

Edit: As for your concern with the native behavior, you don't need to worry about changing the `value` with an `onChange`. `onChange` is an event callback so that we can react to that event.

There is concern with [controlled vs uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) inputs, and they recommend controlling them. That's why I'm supplying the `value` back to the inputs.

Let me know how that goes or if you've got any questions.

Comment: Yep. You are looking for analyzing the event that is triggering onChange and using one handleChange to set the state. event object has a target property that carries what you want.

Comment: This certainly reduces repetition, but there is still an important part of the question unsolved related to the risk of changing the native behavior of the component. Can you think about any solutions for that issue? Is that part of the problem properly explained in the question?

Comment: I mean, why not implement a more simple pattern that does not require the onChange event given that we don´t want to alter the native onChange behavior of the <input> component?

Comment: As far as I know, the `onChange` prop that we have access to on the `<input>` is a callback to use for our purposes so that we can react to changes. We aren't substituting the behavior of how the input handles changes. I.e., it still updates its `value`.

Comment: I added some more info to my answer to hopefully address your concern.

Comment: The point about the native behavior part is that this pattern is forcing the developer to worry about the onChange behavior. So, the idea of not worrying about it is off the table.

Most likely, when this pattern is implemented properly you will have this the handler repeated on every project with the exact same code, making noise and confusing new developers. Is there no way to make this work without it?

Comment: In lots of other frameworks, rather than explicitly passing in an `onChange` to respond to events, you'll wire-up the `value` using a one-way or two-way binding. Is that what you're comparing this React pattern too? React [state is immutable](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state). There's a library we've used called [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview#the-gist) to handle form state, and I'd recommend giving it a shot.

Comment: I'm comparing this pattern to the vanillajs/html alternative where the value is not assigned to the element at "random" moments but when the developer explicitly assigns it... I'm also trying to find a way get control of the exact times that the value is assigned to the actual DOM element to prevent unexpected changes in value while the user is typing in a way that can safely be reproduced by other developers.

Comment: So, summarizing, I'm exploring the idea that input field values should not be assigned in the way generally accepted by the React community and I'm looking for a better alternative...